# JWT multipile authentication

Tags: php, rest, authentication, jwt

Can I use the returned JWT when authenticating with a website to authenticate with another website with the condition both sites share the same encryption key?

I made the authentication with the first website then when I use the key returned to authenticate with 2nd website he said

> 'signature verification failed jwt'

but I used the same key encryption

Comment: If the second server is trying to view the JWT with the same key, it should be able to read it.  Are you sure both servers are really using the same key?  A JWT is supposed to be a standalone token.

Comment: thanks for the answer exactly my problem was a missing character in the key in the 2 nd website

Answer (score 0):

api JWT's can be used across multiple applications.
eg: web app, mobile app etc. 
You should not have any issue in using it.
is the JWT generated by you or 3rd party API's ?